# FirebaseListAdapter showing wrong content for list items

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

The scenario is onn scroll, the new items in my ListView are not getting new content but is instead reusing some of the content that was used for previously loaded items.

```
public void append(final String f, final Activity a, ListView l) {
        final FirebaseListAdapter adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<NoteData>(a, NoteData.class, R.layout.note,
                ref.orderByChild("time")) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(final View v, NoteData model, int position) {
                String k = getRef(position).getKey();
                body.setText(model.getBody());
                title.setText(model.getTitle());
                color.setText(model.getColor());

        AppendDone((HashMap) notes, adapter);
    }
}
```

I understand that if I were using `convertView`, I'd first check if `convertView` is null, but how do I make sure new items get new data?

Comment: Did you reset the `ListView` adapter inside `AppendDone` call?